# How to normalize a table with similar column names?

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

I have an SQL table like so:

```
column(id, name, title, view1, view2, view3, view4);
```

[image: table that lists columns]

where the `view1, view2,...` are boolean fields indicating whether or not a specific table column with `name` is shown or hidden, when a corresponding viewX is selected.

For example, consider a table with column names like `(time, pressure, efficiency, ...)` and various data (see below for definition of "column")

```
time  | pressure | efficiency
----------------------------
00:00 |    53.3  |    39%
00:01 |    53.3  |    39%
00:03 |    53.3  |    39%
```

I wish to select `view1` display mode, where `view1` is to ONLY show `time` column.  Then I may wish to select `view2` display mode where I ONLY want to see `time` and `pressure` columns.  `view3` is to show only `time` and `efficiency`.  `view4` shows all the column names and data `(time, pressure, efficiency)`.

How can I normalize this table?  I am having difficulty figuring out which direction to go.  Do I need to normalize it in the first place?

**Terminology**

To use clear terminology, I will use the word "column" to indicate my HTML table columns use case, where column is (time, pressure, efficiency, etc), and the word "field" to indicate SQL database field.

P.S. My answer seems to be to create a *relation* between the column table and the group table, where column contains values like (time, pressure, efficiency), and group contains (view1, view2, view3, etc).  Based on relation, if relation database table contains a row with (view X, fieldname Y) then the fieldname Y is to be displayed when view X is chosen.  I think it is my answer.

Comment: I think you just might have made your description of the table and its usage ___just a little too cryptic___

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree, and my answer is equally cryptic...

Comment: I maybe added more clarity

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question anymore. You have a database table called "column", which seems to be used to create "views" of another database table, by using booleans. How? You do realize that "column" is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)?

Comment: I am using a column in a difference sense, not the database field name sense.  I have a user-facing table that has table columns.  Examples of my use of `column` are `time, pressure, efficiency`.  To differentiate I will use `column` to indicate the HTML table columns use case, and `field` to indicate SQL database field

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. What do you want to do given what? What do you mean "normalize this table"? Your question doesn't give information relevant to normalization. PS Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of right now. Adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear. PS Clarify via edits not comments. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a seperate table holding the booleans:

```
first_table: column(id, name, title, sort_order);

second_table: column(id, first_table_id, view_no, shown);
```

here the column `shown` holds the booleans.

Comment: Not cryptic at all :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, it copies what is in the question. But it is not a proper CREATE for a table.

Comment: This answer was given before the question was edited. The question has now somewhat changed.

Answer (score 1):

my_table_1(id*, name, title, sort_order);

my_table_2(my_table_1_id*,my_view*,status);

`*` = (component of) PRIMARY KEY

Comment: This feels like EAV model.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya Yep. It's certainly similar - but we know that all the 'attributes' are the same kind of thing.

Comment: what is component of primary key?  In SQL you can only have a static field name, as I understand.  So naming a column `id*` fails ... unless you mean having several ids like `id1`, `id2`, `id3`?  In other words, I'm confused

Comment: @Dennis In the first table, the PRIMARY KEY is (id). In the second table, the PRIMARY KEY is (my_table_1_id,my_view).